# Second Order Differential Equation problem with initial value. Can't integrate further?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> $y$ double prime $- 3y^2 = 0$
>
> $y$ prime $(0) = 4$
>
> $ y (0) = 2$

So this question popped up in my textbook that has me stuck.

My attempt,

> Let y double prime = $v (dv/dy)$

So it becomes,

> $v (dv/dy) - 3y^2 = 0$
>
> $v * dv = 3y^2 * dy$

Integrate both sides,

> $(1/2)v^2 = y^3 + c$
>
> $v = (2y^3 + 2c)^{1/2}$

Since $v = y$ prime and $y$ prime $(0) = 4$

> $4 = ( 0 + 2c )^{1/2}$
>
> $c = 8$
>
> $dy/dx = (2y^3 + 16) ^{1/2}$
>
> $dy (2y^3 + 16)^{-1/2} = dx$

Now...I can't integrate the left side for the life of me.....

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't really understand your initial substitution. Instead, try multiplying through your original equation by $y'$ and using $$y'y'' = \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{1}{2}(y')^{2} \right], \quad 3y^{2}y' = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ y^{3} \right]$$ Applying the initial condition gives the integration constant $C = 0$ and so then it remains to integrate $$y' = \sqrt{2} y^{3/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

At this line $4 = ( 0 + 2c )^{1/2}$ It seems you made a mistake with the constant c $y(0)^3=8$ not 0

$$y''-3y^2=0$$
substitute $p=\frac {dy}{dx} \implies y''=p\frac {dp}{dy}=pp'$
$$pp'-3y^2=0$$
$$pdp=3y^2dy$$
After integration
$$\frac {p^2}2=y^3+K$$
$$y'(0)=4 \, ,\, y(0)=2  \implies K=0$$
$$ {y'^2}=2y^3$$